# ruby bundler default config values

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

How can I get the default values that `bundle` uses for various unconfigured variables? If I try

```
bundle config get disable_shared_gems
You have not configured a value for `disable_shared_gems`
```

Yet I'm sure bundler has some idea of what to do about shared gems, since it keeps trying to install them even though I have versions obtained via `apt install ruby-*`

All I can see via `bundle config get/list` is the PATH variable, which I have set in `~/.bundle/config`. If I don't set `PATH`, it uses my `sudo` capabilities without asking and "helpfully" installs to some system directories.

Comment: what is your question? are you asking whether you are correct? :)

Comment: Let me quote myself: How can I get the default values that bundle uses for various unconfigured variables